# How to query information related to marriage/death dates

Tags: mysql

```
    create users (id, gender, name, birth_date, married_on, died_on, ..)
    create user_relationships (id, user_id1, user_id2, relationship_type)

users (1, "M", "John", ..)
users (2, "F", "Mary", ..)
user_relationships (1, 1, 2, "married-to")
```

How should I query for the following?

```
a. Users who are celebrating their birthdays next week.
b. Users whose marriage dates falling on the next week (Output should include Mr & Mrs John)
c. Users who died, the same time next week.
```

Comment: Have you heard of enumerated types http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html? Besides what have you tried?

Comment: c) See you can predict who is going to die? are you a serial killer?

Comment: c) same time in the previous years.

Comment: @EdHeal I have tried exactly what I have mentioned above, unable to solve [2]

Comment: If you are down voting, can you care to comment. I really would like to know an answer to this.

Comment: The enumerated type is to prevent simple errors. not a fix. why not write some queries?

Comment: I am really interested in a solution for (b) and I don't know how to solve it, thats the reason for asking help.

Comment: at least have a stab at writing a query?

Comment: I tried but couldn't correlate the information across users. I was just looking for pointers to solve the problem. If you aren't interested in providing a helpful pointer, you shouldn't be in this forum. Your time is spent better off doing something more productive. You folks just make life more complicated for people like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > Users who are celebrating their birthdays next week.

   One way would be to see if their age in a week's time is greater than their age today:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   users
   WHERE  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birth_date, CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) >
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birth_date, CURRENT_DATE)
   ```
2. > Users whose marriage dates falling on the next week.

   Similarly:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   users
   WHERE  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, married_on, CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) >
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, married_on, CURRENT_DATE)
   ```
3. > Users who died, the same time next week.

   I'll leave this one as an exercise for the reader.